# What does the acronym ‘PIN’ stand for referring to PIN proteins in plants?

Tags: proteins, plant-physiology, terminology

There are so called [PIN proteins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIN_proteins), or PIN-formed proteins, in plants. What does this acronym mean?

Wikipedia briefly explains the *function* of the protein but not the origin of the name.  It's not explained even in the link-linked review paper, if I'm not missing something.

Answer (score 6):

Like many genes and gene products, PIN proteins were named for a *mutant phenotype* and PIN is not actually an acronym; the source in your link does actually explain this (emphasis mine):

> The significance and function of AtPIN1 was discovered through the phenotype generated by the loss-of-function mutation in the gene: **mutant plants fail to develop floral organs properly and generate naked, pin-like inflorescences, which gave the name PIN-FORMED (PIN)** to the family

Křeček, P., Skůpa, P., Libus, J., Naramoto, S., Tejos, R., Friml, J., & Zažímalová, E. (2009). The PIN-FORMED (PIN) protein family of auxin transporters. Genome biology, 10(12), 249.

Comment: Thanks. So it *is* explained there… (I was lazy to read more than the summary, then I've did just `/\<[Pp][a-z]+(\s|-)[Ii][a-z]+(\s|-)[Nn][a-z]+/` regexp search).

Comment: It begs the question: why was “PIN” all-caps at all? When something is all-caps, it makes people think it’s an acronym. I’m not a geneticist, or even a biologist, by training. So please enlighten me if there’s some rule in the field that justifies all-caps.

Comment: Explaining what actually is a “pin-like inflorescence” would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an acronym; it is an abbreviation of *pinnulate* (or *pinnulated*), which means having the pinnulae of a pinnate leaf properly developed.

Gene symbols written in all caps indicate the wild-type condition of the organism: If a gene is referred to as *PIN1*, it means its product (an auxin transporter) permits normal branching (or at lest does not contribute to malformations); when it is written in lower case, *pin1*, it indicates the gene has a variant associated with a mutant (non-pinnate) phenotype.

*PIN1*: nothing is broken

*pin1*: a single stalk without pinnulae (in the case of Arabidopsis)

If the mutant looks like a pin, it is a co-incidence (probably a mnemonic suggested by a English-speaking teacher). The original meaning derives from *pinna*, which refers to the normal appearance of leaves and flowers.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for your answer. Can you add sources to support your claims and allow folks to background read on your answer?

Comment: Hearsay. That's the explanation I heard from folks in my orbit. Here's one example:

https://youtu.be/jFiqj9NKQfc?t=1452

Apparently, while functionally accurate, it is incorrect as a matter of origin. The discovereres of PIN genes named them *pin-forming*.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC160035/pdf/030677.pdf

They do write gene names in lower case, so that's not where the confusion originated.

There are pictures in the paper illustrating the mutant phenotypes.